# Can't get image URL to put to Database in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I added a tap gesture to profile image that picks images from `iPhone`

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SignUpVC.handleSelectProfileImgView))
profileImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
profileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        profileImage.image = pickedImage
        selectedImage = pickedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have tried to put this image to **STORAGE** afterwards and then get the downloadURL to set in the database

```
func uploadProfileImage(userUID: String, completion: @escaping (_ url: URL?) -> Void) {
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(userUID)

    if let imageData = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) {
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
            guard metadata != nil else { return }
            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                guard let url = url else {return}
                completion(url)
            })
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func signUpPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: (emailTextField.text!), password: (passwordTextField.text!)) { (result, error) in
        if let _eror = error {
            print(_eror.localizedDescription )
        } else {
            let userUID = result?.user.uid
            self.uploadProfileImage(userUID: userUID!, completion: { (url) in
                guard let url = url else {return}
                Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userUID!).setValue(["username":self.usernameTextField.text!, "email":self.emailTextField.text!, "password":self.passwordTextField.text!, "profileImgURL":url])
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I tried not to invoke **uploadProfileImage()** function and just set the values username, email and passsword to database, it works. However, when I call that function uploadProfileImage() and get the URL, it fails.

I have checked the storage and found that the image is successfully uploaded. The problem here is that I fail to get the downloadURL.

Please help me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error")
    } else {
        // your uploaded photo url.
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error")
            } else {
                print(url!)
            }
    )}
}
```

You can use this methods and success of the downloadURL you can get your download url that you can browse in your browser that show your uploaded image.

Comment: It's not what I want, it's kinda like what I did. thanks btw